# Movieclip SOMETIMES starts on wrong frame AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, frames

I am having a strange problem with a game I'm making. 
I will apologize in advance, since I'm new to AS3, so have patience with me :)

I will start by explaining how my game works:

First it adds a main menu screen, on which there is a start button.
When you press the start button, the main menu gets removed, and it adds a level screen.
So there is 3 buttons on the level screen, each representing its own level, and you can only see button 2 if you have finished the first level, etc..

When I press one of the buttons, the game adds the character movieclip and the world movieclip.
All the levels are in the world movieclip, so the first level is on frame 1, and the second on frame 2, etc..

So if I press button1 it goes(simplified):

addChild(world);
world.gotoAndStop(1);

But here's the problem, SOMETIMES it goes to frame 3 instead of frame one. But when I close it down and try again it works fine.
It sometimes does this a few times in a row. 
When the game goes to frame 1 as it's supposed to, there is no problems with the rest of the game.

Has anyone experienced this, or know whats causing it?

Relevant code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.ui.GameInput;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var character:Character;
        public var mainMenu:MainMenu;
        public var backGround:BackGround;
        private var dangers:Dangers;
        public var worldMap:WorldMap;
        public var worldLevel:int;
        public var currentLevel:int;



        public function Main() {

            worldLevel = 1;

            backGround = new BackGround;
            world = new World;
            dangers = new Dangers;
            gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen;
            worldMap = new WorldMap;

            mainMenu = new MainMenu
            addChild(mainMenu)

            character = new Character();


            //-------------- eventlisteners ---------------

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveWorld)

            mainMenu.PlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorldMap)

            //------------------- world buttons --------------------
            worldMap.buttonWorld1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld1)
            worldMap.buttonWorld2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld2)
            worldMap.buttonWorld3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld3)
        }

        //------------------ function go to world map------------------------
        function gotoWorldMap (m:MouseEvent):void
        {
            mainMenu.parent.removeChild(mainMenu);
            addChild(worldMap);
        }

        //----------------- function world 1 -------------------
        function gotoWorld1 (m:MouseEvent):void
        {
            addChild(backGround);

            addChild(world);
            world.gotoAndStop(1);


            addChild(character);
            character.x = 300;
            character.y = 460;
            character.gotoAndStop(3);


            worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);                          
            world.worldDangers.gotoAndStop(1);
            world.SafeGround.gotoAndStop(1);
            world.WorldWalls.gotoAndStop(1);


            currentLevel = 1;

            addChild(gamePanel);
        }

        //----------------- function world 2 ---------------------
        function gotoWorld2 (m:MouseEvent):void
        {
        // same as gotoWorld1, it just goes to frame 2 instead.
        }

        //----------------- function world 3 -----------------------
        function gotoWorld3 (m:MouseEvent):void
        {
        // same again
        }
```

Comment: There is probably a sequence error in your code somewhere. We need code of button 1 click handler, and of the main class regarding to game init routine in order to help better than blind guessing.

Comment: @Vesper I have added what I think is the relevant code. This works, unless the game starts on frame 3 instead of 1.

Comment: What happens if the game starts at frame 2? The same failure or it works correctly? If frame 2 is correct, then look if there's a typo in `gotoWorld3` function. If not, try doing all `gotoAndStop()` prior to doing `addChild()`, maybe there is code on frames in `world` or other parts of it that interfere with what you are setting.

Comment: @Vesper I made it so when I start the game, I can only press button 1, and then when I press it, it either goes to frame 1, and the rest of the game works from there, or it goes to frame 3 (and basically the game works from there, but it's not supposed to go to frame 3). Hmm I'm going to check for typos again, but I still think it's so weird that there is no pattern. It either goes to frame 1 or 3, and it seems completely random which one it chooses (it chooses frame 1 most of the time though).